# Jquery UI form theme

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, webforms

I don't know if this is just laziness from my part or what, but is there any jquery plugin that takes a form (inputs) and build a stylized form with the colorset of the ui theme used in the page? Even better, there is a tut where it explains this idea? It's a little bit tricky to explain (trickier even with my poor english), but I hope that you got the idea.

Any suggestion?

Comment: How would it know the theme? By theme, would it be set by the CSS class names? Or would you want it to look through the DOM and grab color schemes and such?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wijmo](http://wijmo.com) is a jQuery UI and jQuery UI theme based library and they offer [form decorators](http://wijmo.com/widgets/wijmo-open/form-decorator/) in their free version.

Also have a look at the great [jQuery UI CSS Framework documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/css-framework/). You might just be able to solve your problem by just adding the appropriate classes to your form elements.

Comment: thanks dude! Wijmo library is nice, but what I needed was to read well the docs. Thanks

Comment: The jQuery link mentioned above for CSS framework documentation is no longer valid. This was as close as I could find given today's docs: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Comment: I updated the link. The documentation is still there. For some reason it doesn't show up in the navigation but Google still easily found it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you write a simple jQuery widget that traverse your inputs and add jQuery theme styles (ui-..... classes) to them.
You can find the idea at:

http://www.tuttoaster.com/enhancing-forms-using-jquery-ui/12/

The widget is ready at:

http://pastebin.com/bu68sDha

You may need to make some small changes in the widget.

This solution is very good if you have some server side components  that build the form for you and make the final htmls ready (like jsp tags)